# Find total number of mappings

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $A$ be a set of $n$ elements and $B$ be a set of $m$ elements. Show that the   total number of mappings from $A$ to $B$ is $m^n$.

Comment: Have you considered the case, say $n = 2, m = 3$ just to see what's actually going on here?

Answer (score 0):

For each element of $A$ you should choose an element of $B$. You can choose an element of $B$ in $m$ different ways. This should be done repeatedly for $n$ times. So the result $m^n$. Try with $n=1$ and $n=2$ to understand.